# Rewrite template names when debugging with lldb

Tags: c++, templates, lldb

When debugging a c++ program using templates, the output can quickly become unreadable. For this reason it would be convenient, during a debugging session, to rewrite shorten specific type names.

For example

```
void std::__1::vector<std::__1::tuple<unsigned long,
                                      state_change_t,
                                      some::namespace::Board<some::namespace::Tile, unsigned long, 42ul>,
                                      some::namespace::Path<unsigned int, unsigned int>>,
                      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::tuple<unsigned long,
                                                          state_change_t,
                                                          some::namespace::Board<some::namespace::Tile, unsigned long, 42ul>,
                                                          some::namepsace::Path<unsigned int, unsigned int>
                                                          >
                                          >
                      >::some_interesting_method
```

Such an entry can appear multiple times in a single line in a backtrace; This quickly becomes unmanageable. It would therefore be convenient to shorten it to something along the lines of

```
void void std::__1::vector<my_known_type,
                           std::__1::allocator<my_known_type>
                          >::some_interesting_method
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang have an attribute called [`preferred_name`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#preferred-name) that can be used to create template aliases for compile-time diagnostics. It requires a bit of forward declaring, like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Heap;

using IntHeap = Heap<int>;

template<typename T>
struct [[clang::preferred_name(IntHeap)] Heap;
// Possibly add implementation, don't have to yet.
```

Unfortunately, since September 2021, clang won't use this when writing debug symbols. There is a [mailing list thread](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2021-August/152061.html) discussing this change and the diff is [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/2ff049b12ee3fb60581835a28bf9d0acc1723f23).

Clang versions 12 and 13 should still use preferred name in debug symbols, but that's a pretty narrow version window.

Opening a ticket asking to add a flag that enables preferred names in debug symbols might be worthwhile - it seems like a very trivial feature to implement and pretty useful.

Comment: The Swift demangler has a full and a "display" mode, which latter uses the compiler's understanding of the symbol to intelligently shorten it.  Needless to say, lldb takes advantage of that.  If you are asking for clang features, a display mode for the C++ demangler might be more effective - unlike preferred names, you wouldn't have to do the shortening by hand.

Comment: Many thanks for helpful answer and comment.

I happen to be on clang 12, so that is not a blocker. However, I have trouble massaging the compiler to accept a forward declaration for the stdlib classes.

A display mode for the c++-demangler does indeed seem to be the feature I'm looking for, if intelligent enough.

Comment: FYI, this has been addressed to some extent in clang recently when tuning for lldb (which is the default on Apple platforms). See [LLVM 17 Release Notes](https://llvm.org/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#changes-to-the-debug-info). It doesn't change the `DW_AT_name`s but gives the debugger an opportunity to use the preferred name. There have been talks recently to make the demangler be less verbose with heavily templated types (see [this discourse thread](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/llvm-cxxfilt-alternate-renderings-for-particularly-large-demanglings/71303/1), which would help with LLDB backtraces)